# Now.js Won't Send The Client-Side Javascript

Tags: node.js, nowjs-sockets

I'm trying to test now.js with the following code:

```
var connect = require("connect");
var nowjs = require("now");
var io = require("socket.io");

var app = connect().use(connect.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.listen(8180);

var nowIni = nowjs.initialize(app);
```

On the HTML side I'm referencing to it on the `<head>` like this:

```
<script src="/nowjs/now.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The problem is that when I access the page on my browser I get this on the Error Console:

> GET http://192.168.1.78:8180/nowjs/now.js 404 (Not Found)

What am I doing wrong? How to correct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use connect 2.0 this code should work fine:

```js
var connect = require("connect");
var nowjs = require("now");
var http = require("http");
var io = require("socket.io");

var app = connect();
app.use(connect.static(__dirname + '/public'));

var httpApp =  http.createServer(app).listen(8180);

var nowIni = nowjs.initialize(httpApp);
```